How does bound-checking work when slicing Swift collections?
If I declare an empty array
let array: [Int] = []

When slicing from the first item to the end, I get an empty array
array[0...] -> []


However, I cannot index this array. The following line causes the program to crash.
array[0]

Why is that?

array[0] tries to access an element that doesn't exist (the first element of an empty array/slice), can you explain why you think it wouldn't crash?

lowerBound... creates a PartialRangeFrom . When used to subscript a collection, it is converted to
self.lowerBound..<collection.endIndex

where endIndex is

The array’s “past the end” position—that is, the position one greater than the last valid subscript argument.

In particular, array.endIndex... becomes array.endIndex..<array.endIndex, which is an empty range  and a valid argument for subscript(bounds: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element>.
On the other hand, subscript(index: Int) -> Element requires that (emphasis added)

index must be greater than or equal to startIndex and less than endIndex.

Therefore
let array = ... // some array
let slice = array[array.endIndex...]

is valid and returns an empty slice (with slice.startIndex = slice.endIndex = array.endIndex), but
let array = ... // some array
let element = array[array.endIndex]

is not valid and causes a “Fatal error: Index out of range” runtime error.
In your case, array is an empty array and endIndex is zero.

When you declare an empty array like this:
let array: [Int] = []

You are creating an array with no elements. This is why any attempt to access an element by index will cause your program to crash, as there are no elements to access.
To avoid such crashes, you can use safe indexing. Here's an example using safe indexing:
extension Array {
subscript(safe index: Int) -> Element? {
    return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
}

}
Usage:
let array: [Int] = []

if let firstElement = array[safe: 0] {
    print("The first element is \(firstElement)")
} else {
    print("The array is empty or the index is out of range")
}

